# Having trouble finding permissions in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to change my permissions for a database in phpMyAdmin.  I am unable to create a user called 'root' because the only available users are in the format of a*******_*username*.  I cannot find any "Permissions" button in the phpMyAdmin portal.  If anyone could come up with some other way to access permissions, that would be great.  Thanks.  Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Search on the page for "Privileges" (usually upper right on the screen).

Comment: Yeah... couldn't find anything like that on my username.

Comment: I mean, I'm positive that if I had a username like "root" or something, it'll appear.

Comment: First click on your database on the LEFT PANEL, after you did that, Privileges should appear on the UPPER RIGHT of the RIGHT PANEL. I'm using WAMP v2.5, what are you using? Maybe I should post an answer with an image . . .

Comment: I only have phpMyAdmin set up on a web hosting service called 000webhost.com.  localhost just doesn't do it for me, so...

Comment: Would you post a screenshot of what you see? Just edit your question and add the image.

Comment: Uh... do I have enough rep?

Comment: I don't know. Do you see the "edit" link below your question? Click it.

Comment: Hey!!! duh... Let me put an image in my server

Comment: I will give you a hand . . . Refresh your page . . . and add the image to your question by editing it.

Comment: well.... the link is http://jackaplier.netne.net/screenshot.html

Comment: you can vote it back down again :D

Comment: According to the image we are browsing the database. Can you go back? I mean, back OUT of this page? Do you see the violet color links on the top of the screen?

Comment: Access the link again

Comment: Oh.... you mean the breadcrumbs?

Comment: Did you mean like that?

Comment: Well, seems like your webhoster doesn't trust you, so they won't give you enough privileges. I guess you will have to email them or call them. If it's a free account, they will tell you to get a paid one.

Comment: No wonder... I can't use a localhost though, since it will be hard to access in code...

Comment: Hm... what's weird is I can add, but I can't access.  Weird, hmm?

Comment: I believe we are done here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Phpmyadmin uses the setting in the MySQL database for user rights. If you are using a instance on something like aws you may not be able to use root and also you may have more restricted rights than you thing. Look at the users and their rights and verify the credentials you are trying to make are online with your set up.

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with phpMyAdmin's UI, so could you expand on how I would do that?